# ptrace attach to vsftpd hangs

Tags: linux, debugging, ftp, ptrace, vsftpd

I am trying to ptrace a vsftpd server process on linux to be able to get control whenever vsftpd process makes a system call. I start the vsftpd process and pass this process id as command line to the following program which traces vsftpd.

however, when I run the following program it just hangs and does not print anything.Can anyone point out what could be wrong? Thanks a lot for your help!!

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/user.h> 
#include <sys/syscall.h>   /* For SYS_write etc */
#include<sys/reg.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{   pid_t child;
long orig_eax, eax;
long params[3];
int status;
int insyscall = 0;
child = atoi(argv[1]);
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH,child,NULL,NULL);
   while(1) {
      wait(&status);
      if(WIFEXITED(status))
          break;
      orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                 child, 4 * ORIG_EAX, NULL);

    if(orig_eax == __NR_clone || orig_eax == __NR_open || orig_eax == __NR_write)
        { 
if(insyscall == 0) {
            /* Syscall entry */
            insyscall = 1;
            params[0] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                               child, 4 * EBX,
                               NULL);
            params[1] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                               child, 4 * ECX,
                               NULL);
            params[2] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                               child, 4 * EDX,
                               NULL);
    if(orig_eax == __NR_clone)
    {
        printf("\nClone");
    }
    else if(orig_eax == __NR_open)
        printf("\nOpen");
    else if(orig_eax == __NR_write)
        printf("\nWrite");
            printf(" called with "
                   "%ld, %ld, %ld\n",
                   params[0], params[1],
                   params[2]);
            }
      else { /* Syscall exit */
            eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                         child, 4 * EAX, NULL);
                printf("Returned "
                       "with %ld\n", eax);
                insyscall = 0;
            }
        }
        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,
               child, NULL, NULL);
    }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not add some temporary printf status statements? Then you'll be able to see where it is hanging, and then it would be easier to develop theories about why it is hanging. Are you sure wait(&status) is doing what you think? Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the privilege to trace VSFTPD. Run this as root. To test, put the result of `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH,child,NULL,NULL);` into a variable and print it, ie.

```
long result = ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH,child,NULL,NULL);
printf("%ld",result);
```

On my system if result == -1, I do not have permission. If result == 0, I do.